# Having trouble with godaddy htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ /1 [L]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews                
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sayfa-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  menu-detay.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^kategori-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  kategoriler.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$  urun-detay.php?sef=$1&urun_id=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  urun-detay.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bize-ulasin$ iletisim.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

This is my htaccess file and seo links are not working. Im using LINUX hosting and couldnt find anything helpfull.

When i click my seo url on my index like "website.com/product-33v-new-generation" it redirect me to homepage.

```
RewriteRule ^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$ urun-detay.php?sef=$1&urun_id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

This is my seo url link for products

```
RewriteRule ^kategori-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  kategoriler.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
```

And this one is for categories.

But non of them are working for somehow. I have another linux hosting but they are working just fine.

Any help appericiated.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your htaccess Rules file, please do mention sample of URLs and errors which you are getting after hitting your URLs, thank you.

Comment: `When i click my seo url on my index like "website.com/product-33v-new-generation" it redirect me to homepage.` so by which file your homepage should be served?

Comment: RewriteRule ^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$  urun-detay.php?sef=$1&urun_id=$2 [L,QSA]

This line is my product-detail page with seo url -> sef=$1 on htaccess file

Comment: Ok so you mean your home page which is `website.com/product-33v-new-generation` should be served by `urun-detay.php` in backend apache? Kindly confirm once.

Comment: after removing "RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php" this line everything working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php [L]   

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews                
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^sayfa-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  menu-detay.php?sef=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^kategori-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  kategoriler.php?sef=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)-([0-9]+)$  urun-detay.php?sef=$1&urun_id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^urun-([0-9a-zA-Z-_]+)  urun-detay.php?sef=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bize-ulasin/?$ iletisim.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^sitemap\.xml/?$ sitemap.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

***Few fixes in OP's tried htaccess Rules file:***

- You need NOT to use multiple `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` sections as per your shown attempts.
- Need not to use multiple RewriteBase, you could mention it in starting of Rules.
- Also fixed few Rules flags and regex in few of the other rules here.

Comment: thank you everything is working fine. 
For who needs more info i have upgraded my godaddy php version 5.3 to 5.6 also.

Comment: @AlperAslan, your welcome, cheers and happy learning.